# How to use Table Adapter Fill with SQL Server stored procedure with two parameters

Tags: c#, sql-server, tableadapter

I have a stored procedure with two parameters - `beginDate` and `endDate`. I created a table adapter and it looks like it expects two parameters because on the designer screen it shows `@beginDate`, `@endDate`.

When I go to fill it:

```
DateTime beginDate = new DateTime(2016, 5, 1);
DateTime endDate = new DateTime(2016, 5, 31);

this.getDailySalesTableAdapter.Fill(myDataSet.getDailySales, beginDate, endDate);
```

I get an error that argument 3 must be passed with the 'ref' keyword.  When I add the ref keyword, I get the error that argument 3 cannot convert from ref `System.DateTime` to `System.DateTime?`  I am using SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like "Argument 3" is expected to be a nullable DateTime. Change your declaration of `endDate` to:

```
DateTime? endDate = new DateTime(2016, 5, 31);
```

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2010/11/understanding-c-nullable-types.html) is a nice article to understand the nullable types and yes @wablab mentioned correctly you need to declare you datetime variable as nullable datetime